# How do I join two select statements together

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, join, select

I am trying to join two statements together but I’m unsure how to

The first statement is:

```sql
SELECT
  started_at,
  ended_at, 
  Extract ('dow' FROM started_at) AS day_of_week
FROM divvy_full_year
```

The second statement is:

```sql
SELECT
  started_at,
  ended_at,
  (ended_at - started_at) AS ride_length
FROM divvy_full_year
```

I want them to be one statement and not separate.

Answer (score 0):

They're both coming from the same table so simply place all the field sections into one statement:

```
SELECT
    started_at,
    ended_at,
    EXTRACT('dow' FROM started_at) AS day_of_week,
    (ended_at - started_at) AS ride_length
FROM
    divvy_full_year
```